# How to understand error in kubelet logs in the worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I see these errors in the kubelet.log on my worker nodes

```
Feb 11 19:39:41 my-node-ip kubelet[4358]: I0711 19:39:41.666680    4358 log.go:198] http: TLS handshake error from 172.16.4.71:58965: EOF
Feb 11 19:39:42 my-node-ip kubelet[4358]: I0711 19:39:42.121386    4358 log.go:198] http: TLS handshake error from 172.16.4.40:21053: EOF
Feb 11 19:39:45 my-node-ip kubelet[4358]: I0711 19:39:45.001122    4358 log.go:198] http: TLS handshake error from 172.16.4.71:36777: EOF
Feb 11 19:39:45 my-node-ip kubelet[4358]: I0711 19:39:45.455301    4358 log.go:198] http: TLS handshake error from 172.16.4.40:31905: EOF
Feb 11 19:39:48 my-node-ip kubelet[4358]: I0711 19:39:48.333620    4358 log.go:198] http: TLS handshake error from 172.16.4.71:1877: EOF
```

- What does the error "http: TLS handshake error from 172.16.4.71:58965: EOF" indicate?
- What could be these ips `172.16.4.71` and `172.16.4.40` and port correspond to?

What should I understand by this error message?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [document](https://aboutssl.org/fix-ssl-tls-handshake-failed-error/):

> Whenever an SSL/TLS Handshake fails, it’s mostly due to certain things going on with the server, website, and the configuration of its installed SSL/TLS. Presently the culprit is TLS configuration as support for SSL 3.0 is deprecated. However, there’s a distinct possibility that a client-side error can be the reason behind the SSL/TLS Handshake Failed error. And, some of the common ones are like incorrect system time or browser updates.

Also this is an known issue as mentioned in the github [link](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/issues/2142)

> EOF errors seem to be related to a [Go bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50984) and appear on kubernetes 1.22, 1.23 and 1.24. This is not affecting any functional issues and these are generated from core kubernetes. We need to wait until a fix is suggested by kubernetes.

Can you also try this work around to disable the TLS Handshake errors by following this [document](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect).